# CSS FlexBox prevent child from growing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to prevent the yellow child growing and to take just 50% from parent (like the green takes, because has no content), using **just** flex properties (grow, shrink, basis)?

Parent has `flex-direction: column` and both of the children have `flex-basis: 50%`

I know that a fast solution is to set on yellow child `height: 50%` and `overflow: auto` to trigger the scrollbar, but I wanted to achieve that without using the height property.

[image: Illustration of the problem]

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.parent{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.parent div:first-child{
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 200px;
}
.parent div:last-child{
  background-color: blue;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat non magna sit amet sagittis. Praesent auctor sed risus vitae dapibus. Aliquam ex purus, fa
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat non magna sit amet sagittis. Praesent auctor sed risus vitae dapibus. Aliquam ex purus, fa
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat non magna sit amet sagittis. Praesent auctor sed risus vitae dapibus. Aliquam ex purus, fa
  </div>
  <div>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need a [example].

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2o9541gh

Comment: `  flex: 0 0 50%;` not `flex-basis:50%`

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried already... don't work, on msdn documentation it says that flex basis "works" like height when flex-direction is column, but there are some differences, with height: 50% on child I get the result I wanted.

Comment: Flex-basis is the **initial** size before any content is added. It is NOT the same as height/width. If you don't want to exceed 50% you need to use the flex-shrink property

Comment: I tried also flex: 0 0 50%, or playing with the flex-shrink/flex-grow but I can't get it work, I miss something.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to prevent the yellow child growing and to take just 50% from parent (like the green takes, because has no content), using just flex properties?

No.
There are no flex properties that would allow you to solve this issue. The flexbox layout mode takes into account the content of its children and like most CSS does, it will try its best to make content visible.

If you want your yellow box to only take up 50% height you have to decide what will happen to the content that will have no room. Below is one example where setting `overflow-y: scroll` allows the box to reveal the remaining content while still being only 50% height.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.parent{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.parent div:first-child{
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.parent div:last-child{
  background-color: blue;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat non magna sit amet sagittis. Praesent auctor sed risus vitae dapibus. Aliquam ex purus, fa
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat non magna sit amet sagittis. Praesent auctor sed risus vitae dapibus. Aliquam ex purus, fa
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat non magna sit amet sagittis. Praesent auctor sed risus vitae dapibus. Aliquam ex purus, fa
  </div>
  <div>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHUtMbJw8iA is a good watch